# How do I use the Android Wheel in my project?

Tags: android, eclipse, widget

I checked out the source code, but now how do I use this in my project? I'm using eclipse.

http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download the source code, then in Eclipse import the project (Import -> Existing project).

This will add the wheel project, that is an Android Library Project. Then in your project you need to add the wheel project as a dependency. Right click your project, select Properties. There select Android, and to the right click the Add button. More on this [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html)